# Fortran program slower with OpenMP than without it

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I have written the simple Fortran program presented below:

```
PROGRAM TEST
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i,j, k = 20000
real(kind=8) :: start,finish
real(kind=8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: G
allocate( G(k,k))
G=0
call cpu_time(start)
!$OMP PARALLEL
    !$OMP DO
        DO i = 1,k
            DO j = 1,k
                G(j,i) = 1*5    
            END DO
        END DO
    !$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
call cpu_time(finish)
write(*,*) 'TIME', finish-start
DEALLOCATE(G)

allocate( G(k,k))
G=0
call cpu_time(start)
    DO i = 1,k
        DO j = 1,k
            G(j,i) = 1*5    
        END DO
    END DO
call cpu_time(finish)
write(*,*) 'TIME', finish-start
DEALLOCATE(G)
END PROGRAM TEST
```

The first set of loops in the code is parallelized with OpenMP, but it is slower (about 4 times) than the following set of loops which is not.

The results of program I see are:

```
 TIME   1.9760000000000000     
 TIME  0.76400000000000023
```

My CPU has 2 cores and I ran the program with 4 threads

Why  is the OpenMP part slower than the later part? How can I edit my code to make it faster?

I use gfortran compiler with `-fopenmp` flag.

Comment: Read previous posts about cpu_time vs. omp_wtime or system_clock, and about timing dead code with and without optimization and parallelism, and about choosing number of hyperthreads and setting affinity (and about the difference operating system and degree of openmp implementation make).

Comment: Please measure the actual time, not `cpu_time`, if the prolem remains, report back and [edit] the question with the corrected code and measurements.

Comment: Thank you for answers :)